# Data table total row disappears

Tags: excel, datatable

I have a simple problem but it bugs me, I have a data table which is being filled by values from a database. In a normal case, it looks like this:

[image: 11]

But when there is no data in the database, it changes to this:

[image: 22]

When I then have useful data again, this happens:

[image: 33]

Is there a way to prevent this?

Edit (comment from below that might be relevant):
I have a SQL statement as the data source, e.g.: `SELECT Stk, m2 FROM DB_table`. For the sake of replicating it for the screenshots, I then changed it to: `SELECT Stk, m2 FROM DB_table WHERE 1=2` and the total row disappeared

Comment: why is this question light gray in the newest section?

Comment: Pardon? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: i was browsing the "newest questions" section and this question was light gray. like this one: http://i.imgur.com/AhWVneS.png (the one in the middle obviously)

Comment: Good question, I didn't do anything, probably best asked in Meta.

Comment: I tried replicating that on my side, the total row always stick, even when I do not have any rows left... Can you be more precise on how you get to have no rows left in your table? It might help to understand the issue.

Comment: I have a SQL statement as the data source, e.g.: `SELECT Stk, m2 FROM DB_table`. For the sake of replicating it for the screenshots, I then changed it to: `SELECT Stk, m2 FROM DB_table WHERE 1=2` and the total row disappeared.

Comment: Next time use a `@` sign with my name next to it, that way I'll be alerted that you commented, I'm lucky that I stumbled back on that question. -  Why don't you try bringing the whole table in, then filter it via excel filters? Is there a need to filter via the SQL statement?

Comment: @Sifu: Yeah, sorry forgot about the @. The filter cant be done in Excel, the entire table has thousands of rows. It's very strange that this is happening, it's not too annoying but it seems to be a bug.